# Who developed the " symbol, to be used for rashei teyvot or acronyms?

Tags: acronyms

What are the earliest sources for the use of the " symbol before the final letter, to denote an acronym?

This symbol (geresh) can be found in all Jewish languages, including Hebrew, Yiddish, Ladino...and English.

Comment: I think the symbol's placement was a necessity of in-line typesetting. (Compare caret ^ replacing non-linear power notation.) Earlier notations were dots or strokes over the letters, e.g. in Ramban's seal.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10157/603

Comment: However, I can't find it now, but @avi once posted a picture of an early manuscript of Rashi where the quotation mark was used to indicate the Divrei Hamatchil.

Comment: It's not actually a " (quotation mark); it's a gershayim ״. Similarly, a single one is a geresh ׳, not an apostrophe.

Comment: This isn't just a question about the Hebrew language. We use the apostrophes in transliteration (English contexts) too.